# Deploy Mavenized EAR project without packaging to EAR

Tags: performance, maven, deployment, ejb, ear

I have a "mavenized" EAR project like this:

- PARENT

  - EAR
  - EJB
  - WEB

The problem is that I have to do

```
mvn clean package
```

on PARENT project every time I want to deploy. Just after this, I get the EAR and do

```
mvn glassfish:deploy
```

on a running Glassfish instance.

---

### All this process is a bit hassle in development environment!

I just want to know if there is a faster way to work with EJB, Maven and Glassfish, like deploying target contents without the need of packaging EAR.

PS: I'm already using "jrebel-maven-plugin" that does hot-deploy ONLY when EAR was initially deployed.

Comment: jrebel-maven-plugin does nothing but generates a rebel.xml configuration file for all the modules in the project. Yes, you deploy the ear for the first time, and given JRebel is enabled on the Glassfish instance, you will not have to assemble it again for most of the changes you do in development.

Comment: @AntonArhipov as far as I know, the Eclipse JRebel plugins does the same. As a feature TIED to the IDE, I prefer not to use these plugins on POM anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michel,
why don't you deploy your app from your IDE? I understand that it may take a bit more time to configure development environment, but it really worth the effort. I truly enjoy configuration: Eclipse + m2eclipse + Java EE server.

Download Eclipse for Java EE developers, add plugin m2eclipse(included in Eclipse Juno), import your project as maven project, add application server to eclipse, and run your app on it. Application will be deployed on server by default as exploded archive in less than 10s, what should be huge improvement for you.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers and sorry I forgot to reply this thread. Now I'm using full Eclipse JavaEE environment like you said. :)